# Звідки походить вираз "цирк на дроті"?

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Зазвичай фразу "цирк на дроті" можна зустріти, коли йдеться про щось абсурдне ([приклад](http://prodereban.com.ua/news/cirk-na-droti-2-yak-uxvalyuvali-pidvishhennya-tarifu-na-pro%D1%97zd-u-kropivnickomu-234711/) у заголовку новин).

Але як з'явився цей вислів? Чи має він стосунок до якихось акробатичних номерів із використанням дротів, чи це може бути уривок з якогось анекдоту у формі телефонної розмови ("Алло, цирк на дроті.")?

Обговорення [тут](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=113953) згадує, що і в білоруській мові він вживається.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Воно, ймовірно, не з російської. Бо:

   1. «Цирк на дроте» знаходить значно менше результатів, ніж «цирк на дроті»: і в гуглі, і в гугл-книжках — я це при тому, що росіян і російськомовних значно більше, ніж укранців і україномовних.
   2. Росіяни, шукаючи етимологію цього виразу, самі часто звертаються до українсько-білоруської версії.
   3. <sub><s>В російській мові немає слова «дріт»</s> — не аргумент, у російській мові є *застаріле* слово «дрот».</sub>
2. Воно, ймовірно, не з польської. Бо «cyrk na drucie» знаходить і в гуглі, і в гугл-книжках *ще менше результатів*, ніж навіть російський варіант.

Власне розподіл в гуглі та гугл-книжках такий: *<sub>укр.</sub>* «цирк на дроті» ([215](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%22&num=100&start=200), [24](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%22&num=100)) > *<sub>рос.</sub>* «цирк на дроте» ([170](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22&num=100&start=100), [14](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%22&num=100)) > *<sub>біл.</sub>* «цырк (з помилкою: цирк) на дроце» ([82](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%86%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%22+OR+%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%22), [5](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%86%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%22+OR+%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%22&num=100)) > *<sub>пол.</sub>* «cyrk na drucie» ([26](//www.google.com/search?q=%22cyrk+na+drucie%22&num=100), [2](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cyrk+na+drucie%22&num=100)).

Наразі я схиляюся до білоруської версії. Чому, адже влучань ще менше ніж у росіян?

1. По-перше, у білорусів найдавніші трапляння. Причому не в гуглі, а в гугл-книжках. У 1992 вийшло дві книжки:

   - *[Яўсееў Р. М. Цырк на дроце: Сатыра, гумар / Рыгор Яўсееў. — Мінск: Мастацкая літаратура, 1992. — 190 с.: іл. — ISВN 5340009238: 14 р., 700](//books.google.com/books?id=bIOHtgAACAAJ)* — судячи з назви, збірка анекдотів (чи іншого гумору).
   - *Карней I. Цырк на дроце.., або Балансаванне над безданню: [Па матэрыялах гутаркі з дырэктарам Мінскага цырка І. С. Пашкевічам] //Звязда. — 1992. — 23 крас* — за матеріалами інтерв'ю з директором Мінського цирку.

   В обох «Цырк на дроце» міститься **в назві**. Причому, якщо назву другої ще можна сприйняти буквально (наприклад, «Цирк на зв'язку [бо це інтерв'ю],.. або балансування над безоднею»), то назва першої точно відбиває якусь фразу, що вже існувала на момент видання (як мінімум, це фраза з якогось твору з книги, як максимум — відомий вислів). Це підтверджує також висловлення з форуму «слышано в Минске в 1980[-x] гг».

   <sub><s>А російське «цирк на дроте» трапляється 14.11.1989 й українське «цирк на дроті» трапляється у 15.12.1990 та 20.06.1992</s> — неправда, це просто баґ гугла у визначенні дати документа (документи начебто з 1989–1990 описують події 2002, а 1992 — взагалі 2016). Гугл не знаходить українських, російських і польських сторінок до 2000 року. *Update*: Міжнародний Google знаходить український журнал [«Зустрічі» 1994 року (№ 8)](//books.google.com/books?id=KtEtAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%22) — але справи це не міняє, в білорусів все одно давніші результати (причому в самих назвах книжок).</sub>
2. Навіть якщо вираз походить не з Білорусі, білоруси з ним значно більше поріднилися, ніж українці/росіяни/поляки. Вони використовують його для назв статей про щось недоладне, для заголовків гумористичних тем — вони вважають його питомо білоруським виразом і [радіють, що його додано як стікер у Viber](https://tech.onliner.by/2016/04/26/viber-7).
3. «Цирк на дроті» знайдено в російській повісті [«Снега полярные зовут» О. Антонова (1973, журнал «Современник»)](//books.google.com/books?id=E3c0AQAAIAAJ&q="%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5") — але в білоруській вимові: «на дро**ц**е». За сюжетом, один з персонажів (білорус?) постійно кидає цю фразу, а головний герой його не розуміє. Це лише доводить білоруську версію.
4. [Білоруське відео про цей вираз](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmZ8NPrR9Fw).

   Коротко:

   - мовець каже, що походження точне фрази йому невідомо;
   - мовець намагається довести, що вираз більше білоруський, аніж український, російський чи польський (мовляв, в білоруській мові він загальновідомий і літературний, в той час як у інших народів менш відомий, часто лише сленговий і поширений здебільшого в регіонах біля Білорусі);
   - мовець не пояснив, чи це про акробата на дроті, чи про телефонний дріт (по-моєму, натякаючи на можливість обох варіантів).

Питання, чи це про дріт, по якому ходить акробат, чи про телефонний дріт («на дроце» у значенні «на зв'язку») залишається відкритим. У Білорусі він уживається в обох контекстах:

- Акробат на дроті: [стікер у Viber](https://content.onliner.by/news/2016/04/default/2496f7f8bf32418c809d41b24569a5d1.png).
- В контексті телефону:

  - Хочаш званіць адвакату, ды крык абрываецца ў роце – /
    у слухаўцы дрэсіраваная малпа: “Алё! Цырк на дроце!” *[Хочеш дзвонити адвокату, та крик обривається в роті — / в трубці дресировані мавпи: "Алло! Цирк на дроті!"]* *<sub>//Андрэй Хадановіч, «Восень на вогнішчы» (2004)</sub>*.
  - — Алё, цырк на дроце. Я вас уважліва слухаю. — Салют! Ля апарата — увесь танцпол! *[— Алло, цирк на дроті. Я вас уважно слухаю. — Салют! Біля апарата — весь танцпол!]* *<sub>//[З Живого Журналу](http://kabierac.livejournal.com/262726.html)</sub>*.
- У назві вищенаведеної книги «Цырк на дроце.., або Балансаванне над безданню: [Па матэрыялах гутаркі з дырэктарам…]» я припускаю, що могла мати місце гра слів з обома варіантами.

У Білорусі цей вираз існує ще в іншому варіанті: «цуд на дроце» («чудо [диво] на дроті»). Білоруси [сперечаються](//belarus.dirty.ru/tsyrk-na-drotse-560756/#11229772) щодо того, яка форма давніше, хоча більшість знають варіант саме з цирком. Можливо, що «цуд на дроце» — це лише результат змішання «цырк на дроце» і «цуд(ы) ў рэшаце» («[диво/чудеса в решеті](http://sum.in.ua/s/resheto)»).

<sub>Знайшов українську повість 1982 року видання з цим словосполученням — Галина Пагутяк, [«Лялечка і Мацько»](http://testlib.meta.ua/book/170341/read/) — але це істотно нічого не змінює, адже російська повість «Снега полярные поют», де вираз наведено в білоруській фонетиці, однаково був раніше.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Безумовно "цирк на дроті" пов'язаний саме з еквілібристикою. Серед галичан це дуже поширений вислів.  Так само і в Польщі "cyrk na drucie" - це обурений вигук здивування, як напр. "що це за комедія!", де йдеться не про цирк і не про комедію а про якісь непорядні дії, зухвалі махінації, намагання когось явно "розвести". Згоден з попереднім коментарем про додаткову експресивність виразу.

Ось тут приклад з польської преси [...niektóre listy to po prostu tzw CYRK NA DRUCIE!!](http://www.iswinoujscie.pl/artykuly/33980/artykuly/33980/?page=3&sort=DESC)="Деякі партійні списки - це просто-таки т.зв. ЦИРК НА ДРОТІ...

А тут приклад зі "[Словника сучасного українського сленгу](http://www.dimaname.ru/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-10/)":

> ЗАМОРОЧУВАТИ, -ую, -уєш, недок. Незрозуміло поводитись. От заморочує — прямо цирк на дроті.

Answer (score 1):

Якщо "одеська мова" таки існує:) то цирк на дроті один з найпопулярніших "одесизмів". Загалом, в одеській говірці кілька десятків таких сталих виразів українського походження. Наприклад: дурдом веселка - майже відповідник до "цирку на дроті")

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/333)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian.SE! Відповідь повинна містити, власне, відповідь на запитання. У даному випадку, запитання стосується етимології. Будь ласка, погляньте [оцей допис](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), де написано про наші критерії оцінки хороших відповідей. Ви можете відредагувати [edit] свою відповідь і додати до неї матеріал, що зробить її корисною.

Comment: на жаль, джерела, яке підтверджує мою думку, надати не можу, але на майбутнє собі занотував, як треба відповідати) дяк